# hibernate one to many remove list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities with oneToMany releationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FATHER")
@Audited(withModifiedFlag=true)
@XmlType
public class Father{

    @Column(name="FATHER_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "father", orphanRemoval = true, cascade =     {CascadeType.ALL})
    List<Son> childrens;
    //getter and setter for id, only getter for childrens.
}

@Table(name="CHILDREN")
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag=true)
public class Children{

    @Column(name="CHILDREN_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FATHER_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Father father;
}
```

Now in the Father DAO i want to remove all children using this:

```
Father persistentFather = entityManager.find(Father.class, fatherId);
persistentFather.getChildrens().clear();
entityManager.merge(persistentFather);
```

And i'm getting the following exception:

```
3:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/sample.web] threw exception         [Request processing failed; nested exception is     org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a];     constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could     not execute statement] with root cause
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into     ("MYDB"."CHILDREN_AUD"."FATHER_ID")
```

Why can't hibernate understand the father_id from the father object ? Should i have a father_id field in Children ?

I know that nothing is special here but i couldn't find any solution after searching for couple of hours...

Hope someone can help

Comment: First, what is the "NLNK_A"."CHILDREN_AUD" table?  Second, Child already has a "FATHER_ID"; defined in a join column it acts as a foreign key to the Father's id field.  It is marked insertable/updateable =false though, so it cannot be changed through the relationship, so you need some other mapping to the field in order to set a value to it.

Comment: Chris, this table is the audit table of children. And as for the mapping - you mean i have to have something like fatherId (as mentioned in the question) ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly, but this is what I think is happening. When you call `father.getChildren().clear()`, you are just breaking the relation between father and its children, meaning `FATHER_ID` is set to null, and children are updated. This should work because of `orphanRemoval = true`, but I think somehow Hibernate Envers (which I assume you are using for auditing) is picking this up as an update of `MarkupSubRule`, instead of (or before) deletion, and tries to insert NULL into `CHILDREN_AUD.FATHER_ID`. To check if Envers really is causing this problem, you can temporary disable it and try again. If it is ok for you, you can change `FATHER_ID` in audit table `CHILDREN_AUD` to accept null values.